# I need to make a "server" that can handle multiple long lasting connections of streaming data

Tags: python, asyncsocket

I need to read and plot data in real time from multiple Android phones simultaneously. I'm trying to build a server (in python) that each phone can connect to simultaneously, which will receive the data streams from each phone and plot in real time, using matplotlib. I'm not very experienced in socket programming, although I know the basics (single request servers and such). How should I go about doing this? I looked at asyncore, SocketServer, and other modules, but I'm not sure I grasp how to allow multiple long standing connections.

I was thinking I should create a new thread for each phone (although I'm not sure if it's safe to pass a socket to a new thread), but I also want to be able to plot using subplots (eg, 4 plots side by side), although this is not that important.

I just need a point in the right direction. Small code samples appreciated to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using threads due to the Python's implementation of threading might lead to a degraded performance, depending on what your threads do.

I'd suggest using a framework for building asynchronous server. A one such framework is [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/). Using asynchronous event loop you can do calculations while other "threads" (in case of gevent, greenlets) are waiting for I/O and thus getting better performance. The model is also ideal for long-lasting idle connections.